# How did individual Democratic Super-delegates vote at the roll call convention?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, hillary-clinton, bernie-sanders

How did individual super-delegates wind up voting at the nomination convention?

Note:  I don't think this question is trivial.  It's fairly easy to find who they publicly endorsed, but not every super-delegate endorsed a candidate, and some super-delegates wound up switching from Sanders to Clinton.  Meanwhile, some people at the convention abstained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The individual delegates tell their votes to the state representative and then the results are announced by state (no individual roll call).  You can see the list of [state results](http://www.thegreenpapers.com/PCom/?20160727-0) but even if you drill down into the state, you won't see how individuals voted.

For example, in [Alabama](http://www.thegreenpapers.com/P16/AL-D) you can see that six of the superdelegates voted for Clinton and one abstained.  But even those numbers may not be correct for all states.  In [Pennsylvania](http://www.thegreenpapers.com/P16/PA-D), one of Bernie Sanders' pledged delegates apparently voted for Hillary Clinton.  She had 106 pledged delegates and he had 83, but in the final vote she received 126 delegates to his 82.

There is a [list of endorsements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Democratic_Party_superdelegates,_2016), but they don't show the final vote went.